# "Whichever ONE/ONES you choose DO/DOES not matter"

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement, relative-clauses, interrogatives

Is it grammatical to say

> Whichever ones you choose does not matter

or do I have to say

> whichever ones you choose do not matter?

Because "it doesn't matter whichever one you choose" is legitimate, I was curious as to the grammaticality of its un-extraposed counterpart.

Also, is it grammatical to say

> Which ones you choose do not matter?

If not, please explain the reason as to why it is not grammatical.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Whichever ones you choose does not matter.
> 2. Which ones you choose does not matter

Sentence (1) is perhaps ambiguous. I think the Original Poster wants *whichever ones you choose* to be understood as an interrogative clause. In this case the sentence means something like:

- The answer to the question *Which ones are you going to choose?* is not important.

If this is what the Original Poster wants to say then we do not need the *-ever* suffix here. Sentence (2) is a much better sentence than sentence (1).

Notice that the whole interrogative clause *which ones you choose* is the Subject of the sentence. The noun phrase *which ones* is the Direct Object of the verb *choose* within the clause *which ones you choose*. It is not the Subject of the verb *does*. Because the whole interrogative clause is the Subject of the larger sentence the verb takes third person singular agreement:

- [Which ones you choose] does not matter.

You can compare this with a simpler sentence:

- [What she said] does not matter.

Notice that we cannot use plural verb agreement if the Subject of the sentence is a clause:

- *[What she said] do not matter. (ungrammatical)

---

**Extra note 1:**

It might be useful to know that native speakers do not like to use clauses as the Subjects of sentences. We find these types of sentences difficult to process. We often avoid this by using a dummy pronoun, the word *it*, as the Subject of the sentence and moving the clause to the end of the sentence where it will function as a Complement of the verb. If we do this with the Original Poster's sentence, we get:

- It does not matter [which ones you choose].

**Extra note 2:**

This sentence looks very similar to a conditional sentence:

- Whichever ones you choose, it does not matter.

This sentence has a very different structure to the one in the Original Poster's example. Here the Subject of the main clause is the pronoun *it*. The interrogative clause *whichever ones you choose* is functioning as an Adjunct in the sentence. It tells us the set of situations in which *it does not matter*. This type of sentence is called an *exhaustive conditional*. In exhaustive conditionals like this one, we definitely *do* need to add the suffix *-ever* to the interrogative word:

- *Which ones you choose, it does not matter. (ungrammatical)

**Extra note 3**:

It is possible—but unlikely—that in sentence (1) the phrase *whichever ones you choose* is a noun phrase. With this reading, this noun phrase is a special type of construction called a *fused relative construction* (or a *free relative*). If we read the sentence like this, it means:

- Those things that you choose do not matter.

In this sentence the phrase *whichever ones you choose* is a plural noun phrase headed by the plural noun *ones*. So the larger sentence now has a plural Subject and the verb *do* must take plural agreement:

> 2. [Whichever ones you choose] do not matter.

Because it is in a fused relative clause construction, we have to put the suffix *-ever* on the relative word. With this intended meaning the following sentence is ungrammatical:

- *Which ones you choose do not matter. (ungrammatical)

Answer (score 3):

It is not idiomatic to use the plural form of *one* in the expression: *whichever ones*.
The idiomatic expression is

> **Whichever one** you choose

which is equivalent to

> You can pick/select **any** that you want.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whichever%20one%2Cwhichever%20ones&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhichever%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhichever%20ones%3B%2Cc0) backs this up with the following chart, the expression **whichever one** (blue line) is by far the most common,

[image]

and the same results are repeated in the British English and American English corpora.

Examples taken from Google Books

- If you decide to only keep one, you'll have to decide which one to keep. Do you keep hers or his? **Whichever one you choose**, you'll obviously have to provide your financial planner with an update of your new marital status, your new income, ...
- He replied, “**Whichever one you wish**."
- The point is that **whichever one you choose** is the right one. There isn't a best one.
- Well, **whichever one you want**. Did your old missies dress you every morning? Lord, Lettie! Whichever one you want – pink or blue: you decide.
- Go in and take **whichever one you please.**
- 'Just pick **whichever one you like**, apart from the big one. They'll bring you luck. And I've got a spare dreamcatcher.' 'Awww, thank you, Mum. I wouldn't want my dreams ... roaming around the flat. It's good to trap them, in a window.

The second clause in the OP's example omits the subject pronoun

> does not matter

The appropriate pronoun which agrees with the negative auxiliary verb *does not* is **it**

> Whichever **one** you choose, **it doesn't** matter.

To whom it matters is not specified. The speaker could be implying any one of the following

> Whichever **one** you choose, [**it**] doesn't matter (*to* *me*/*him*/*her*/*us*/*them*)
>
> Whichever **one** you choose, [**it**] doesn't matter (*to* anyone but you.)

If the plural pronoun, *ones*, is used in the first clause, the pronoun in the following clause should be plural because the ‘things’ being chosen is more than one.

> Whichever **ones** you choose, [**they**] don't matter.

However, it doesn't rule out the possibility of there being a different subject in the second clause. In which case, a pronoun *MUST* be used in order to clarify.

Whichever **ones** you choose, **it doesn't** matter (*to* *me*/*him*/*her*/*us*/*them*).

Answer (score 0):

"whichever one|ones you choose" there  is understood to be the semantic equivalent of "your choice", whether you're choosing one item or several, and thus the verb will be *singular*.

{Your choice} doesn't matter.

> Whichever ones you choose doesn't matter. We have all colors in stock.

P.S. I don't disagree with snailplane's view that it's a rather clumsy sentence, but it's a clumsiness many native speakers share.

Comment: So just "which ones you choose doesn't matter"  is not grammatical?

Comment: "Grammatical" in the purest sense means "that's how most native speakers of the language talk". So it's a fuzzy term. There are situations where quite a large number of speakers, though certainly not the majority, will say something in a certain way, as we have here, and for these situations we use the term "marginal". I would call that sentence "marginally grammatical".

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple:

> *"Whichever"* is always **"singular"**.
>
> *"Whichever"* means **‘any one at all’** or **‘it doesn’t matter which’**.

http://www.e4thai.com/e4e/images/pdf/collins_cobuild_english_grammar_collins_digital_edition.pdf speaks only of singular **whoever,
wherever, however, whatever, or whichever**.

Here is another good discussion: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whomever.1433232/

In any case all references tell us that **whoever,
wherever, however, whatever, or whichever** are **"singular"** so in your case the first sentence is correct while the second one is not:

- Whichever ones you choose doesn't matter. (Several things or people that/whom you choose)
- Whichever one you choose doesn't matter. (One thing or person that/whom you choose)

Let me explain why:

*Whichever ones* is a **'set/amount/group/array'** and is **'singular'** and *whichever one* is **'one thing'** ans is also **'singular'**. With singular we use **'it'** so it's **'it does not matter'**.

Explanation:

- It doesn't matter whichever book you take. (One book)
- It doesn't matter whichever books you take. (An amount of books; two or more)

Another example of **'plural'**:

- Whichever of the three questions did you like most? Whichever one did you like most? (Only one question)
- Whichever two of the three questions did you like most? - Whichever ones did you like most? (Any two questions out of the three)

With living creatures:

- Does it matter whichever one is going there first? - (One person)
- Does it matter whichever ones are going there first? - (A group of two or more people)

*Notice!* It is **"Does"** not **"do"** because here we don't mean **'How many people?'** instead we mean **'A group consisting of how many people?'**

Comment: Hmm ... "You can have whichever books take**s** your fancy" "Whichever people **has** already finshed ....". <-- They both seem ungrammatical. The word *whichever* doesn't seem to be particularly singular to me.

Comment: You are refering to 'books' and 'people' here. Books are, people are, but whichever is. It is still singular.

Comment: No, I'm afraid you've accidentally made that up. It is not true!!! [See here for 5,000 reasons that that's not true](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whichever+are%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=AIEbWNW-MNP38Afwp72YBQ#q=%22whichever+are%22&tbm=bks). However, as you noted "people are" and "books are". As it happens "ones are" too. And it is "ones" that we see in OP's example. However, "ones" is not the subject of the verb *does*. Neither is "whichever ones". If it was then the verb would take plural agreement. ...

Comment: ... The reason it does not is because the subject is a clause. Clauses nearly always take singular verb agreement. That's why the verb's singular. *Whichever* can be both singular or plural when it occurs in fused determiner head constructions.

Comment: Actually it's much simpler: Does refers to 'it' and not to whichever.

Comment: In whitedevil's question the second is incorrect and i can't see why it so difficult to understand. You can't say It do not matter whichever ones you take.

Comment: We're not talking extrapositions, we're talking about the sentences without *it*. The word *whichever* is not singular.

Comment: @Araucaria Show me where it is written that this particular pronoun is not singular? That's something really strange you're saying. it is exlusively singular.

Comment: Well, did you see the five thousand examples from published books where *whichever* without any following plural noun took plural verb agreement? And that was only with one particular verb. Multiply that out by the tens of thousands of different verbs in English and you have tens of millions of examples showing that that claim is wrong.

Comment: @Araucaria You are misunderstanding the singularity of a relative pronoun. Take this example This rule is accompanied by its converse: “Whatever is founded in a secondary substance is also founded in whichever are the primary substances of that secondary.” whichever isn't plural here it links to the noun sybstances that is plural, that's why it's are, not is. Yet, whichever means 'it doesn't matter which one', So it still is Whichever substances are mentioned is (not are) not important.

Comment: No, that's not how the grammar works. It's "Whichever substances are mentioned is  not important" because the subject of the verb "*is*" is the interrogative clause [Whichever substances are mentioned] not the noun phrase [Whichever substances]. The noun phrase [Whichever substances] is the subject of "are mentioned" not "does not matter". And notice that it is "are mentioned" and not "is mentioned"! So in the larger sentence its "[Whichever substances are mentioned] does not matter." Within the interrogative clause it is "[Whichever substances] are mentioned". The subjects there are ...

Comment: ...  the bracketed constituents in my rendering..

Comment: @Araucaria We are running circles here... I understand it perfectly well. [Whichever substances] is plural, yes, but [Whichever] is singular. Which of the substances are mentioned?

Comment: You could easily have "Whichever are mentioned" so how is "whichever" singlular?

Comment: You simply omitted the noun previously mentioned. You can't say Whichever are mentioned without context. You need to tell the person to what you link Whichever? The cars are amazing. Whichever are most interesting to you? The drinks were good. Whichever was(were) your favourite?

Comment: Well, there you have it! You've nailed it. The issue is whether what "whichever" *represents* is semantically singular or plural. "Whichever" like other interrogative words inherits its number from its antecedent. In itself it is not either singular or plural. :)

Answer (score -2):

> [Whichever ones you choose] don't matter.

This sentence is fine as it is. But as commenters have said, it might not be the best sentence available. @snailplane♦ already suggested a better alternative.

The word - *whichever* - is a determinative. So when it precedes the head in a Noun Phrase structure, it's grammatically correct.

The part - *whichever ones you choose* - is a free choice relative construction.

Note that ***which*** can't occur in a free choice relative construction. Therefore, the following sentence is wrong -

> * Which ones you choose don't matter. [INCORRECT]

However, ***which*** can occur in an embedded interrogative clause.

> I don't know [which one you chose].

Comment: Thank you! But I don't get what you mean by this; which one you choose in which one you choose doesn't matter can be viewed as an ordinary embedded interrogative clause as well. In that respect, this sentence is fine.

Comment: I have the same problem with "whichever ones [that] you choose *don't* matter" as I do with "macaroni and cheese *are* a decent lunch".  Yes, those subjects have plural forms, but I prefer a verb that agrees with their singular semantics.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan I think that's because MFI is reading it as a fused relative clause. However, you and I are more likely to read it as an interrogative clause, which is why we would expect singular verb agreement here.